# Apache CXF: Publishing a Web Service (SOAP over JMS) with failover feature

Tags: soap, jms, cxf, failover

Apache CXF: It seems that failover feature is available, but for clients. I need to create a service that is binded to a JMS queue of a particular JMS server. The JMS provider(TIBCO) has capability of failing over. Is there a way in which I can allow my service to failover to another JMS server at runtime and publish it there? If cxf is not capable of doing this, is there any other framework which allows failover feature for publishing services over JMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vidish,

Server :
The TIBCO EMS administrator needs to configure the FT connection factory and provide the connection factory name and URL details to you. Configure those details in your JMS configurations - that's all needed for server.

Client :
TIBCO JMS API provides failover mechanism. Sample code is available in TIBCO EMS installation folder.

Joy

Comment: Thanks Joy. Yes, I overlooked the capability of Tibco API and was believing that CXF should provide this. I was able to resolve this by using Initial Context Factory provided by Tibco which has inbuilt capability of maintaining session and failing over in case primary goes down.